# How can we display number values in UILabels in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am very new for iOS and in my app I am integrating services and after getting response from service I am storing the values in Array-list.

When I load that array list values in tableList showing exception like:

> _Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d7ca000'

```
 McoIdArray:-(
106314100491,
106314100492,
106314100493,
106314100494,
106314100495
)

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    Cell = (CoridersCell *)[tableList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (Cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CoridersCell" owner:self options:nil];
        Cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    Cell.mcoId.text = [McoIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return Cell;
}
```

Comment: BTW - unrelated to the issue but you should know that it is standard practice to name methods and variables to start with lowercase letters and class names with uppercase letters.

Comment: enable exceptional breakpoint and see where it hits after crash

Comment: how you initialised the array ?

Comment: what is McoIdArray? WHere and how you initialised it ?@AbhiRam

Comment: what is Cell and tableList ? WHere did you declarew them ?

Comment: actually i ma declare this McoIdArray in my main class and i ma sending this array list to this tableList class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are assigning an NSNumber instance instead of an NSString. You should format the number to a string like this:

```
NSNumber* number = [McoIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.mcoId.text = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@", number];
```

If you want to have more control over number formatting you can use NSNumberFormatter.

Comment: what could be the difference from the answers below to yours ? Is localizedStringWithFormat if fail safe way to do ?@phix23

Comment: @Mr.T other answer might also work, but localizedStringWithFormat creates a localized string with the current locale and it would also work if the object is actually a string already

Comment: If it's a string already, the question wouldn't have been asked. And there's certainly no reason at all to use `localizedStringWithFormat:` on an `NSString`.

Answer (score 1):

Your array contains instances of `NSNumber`, not `NSString`. So you can't directly assign the value from the array to the label's `text` property. You must first convert the `NSNumber` to an `NSString`.

One option is to use the `stringValue` method.

```
Cell.mcoId.text = [McoIdArray[indexPath.row] stringValue];
```

Also note the use of modern syntax to access the array.

Replace the line:

```
Cell.mcoId.text = [McoIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

with the line I show above.

Comment: Not possible. You have some other issue then. The code in my answer can't possibly result in the identical error you posted in your question.

Comment: if i coment that line there is no exception coming'

Comment: What is the exact error you get if you use the line posted in my answer?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d7ca000'

Comment: That's the error from your code. What's the error from the code in my answer? Did you replace the line `Cell.mcoId.text = [McoIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` with the line shown in my answer?

Comment: I think `[McoIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` will return NSNumber

Comment: @ShehzadAli Yes it does. That's the whole point of my answer. Explaining that and providing the solution.

Comment: I think he is misunderstanding. @Abhi you must write this `Cell.mcoId.text = [[McoIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];`

Comment: @ShehzadAli Or they can use the answer I provided. Given the edit you tried to make on my answer, I think it is you that doesn't understand.

Comment: @AbhiRam You must be doing it wrong. As I state in my answer, you need to replace `Cell.mcoId.text = [McoIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` with `Cell.mcoId.text = [McoIdArray[indexPath.row] stringValue];`. Did you do that?

Comment: yeah I miss read replace the line and i though he is getting exception because of `Cell.mcoId.text = [McoIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` that's why i added string value.

Comment: @ShehzadAli They are getting an exception due to `Cell.mcoId.text = [McoIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`. That's why my answer tells them to replace that line.

Comment: @rmaddy you are right. I agree. I made and edit because I miss read.

Comment: @rmaddy is it the right way to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in the OP question ?

Comment: @Mr.T It would be if the OP called `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` on `tableView` instead of some unknown variable named `tableList`.

Comment: @AbhiRam Apparently you never actually implemented my answer correctly.